# Save MKPolyline as NSData in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, nsuserdefaults, nsdata

My iOS application needs to store an `MKPolyline` inside of an `NSUserDefault`. I've been doing a lot of research, and I now know that:

- NSUserDefaults are a subclass of NSCoder
- MKPolyline is not a subclass of NSCoder

As a result, it is rather difficult to save a polyline to [nsuserdefaults](/questions/tagged/nsuserdefaults). I have attempted to convert the MKPolyline into NSData:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:routeLine]; // routeLine is an MKPolyline
[defaults dataForKey:@"key"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

When I try to convert the polyline to NSData, I get this error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MKPolyline encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xba1fd70

I can successfully perform the above code when using an **MKPolylineView** however then I have issues getting the MKPolyline back out of the View. I found [this Q/A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698103/mkpolyline-nskeyedarchiver-nsdata-sigabrt) but it doesn't solve my issue because it would change the way my app functions.

**How can I save an MKPolyline?** Can I subclass it, if so what would that entail? Or is there a way to do it with the MKPolylineView? Am I missing something with NSCoder?

Answer (score 4):

While you can implement `NSCoding` yourself for `MKPolyline`, and then construct an `NSData` representation and store that in `NSUserDefaults`, it might be better to represent the `MKPolyline` using arrays and dictionaries, which `NSUserDefaults` can directly handle.

Construct an array of dictionaries which encapsulate the x and y values for each point, and store *that* in `NSUserDefaults` instead of the `MKPolyline`.

When loading defaults, get the array, loop through the dictionaries reconstructing the points, and then re-create the `MKPolyline`.

Comment: As a side note, the best way to implement this is probably a category on `MKPolyline`.

Comment: Sure, something like `-arrayValue` and `-initWithPointArray:`.